# array_push(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, string given

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

This is my code, and when I run this function I get this: `array_push(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, string given` I trying to add value to the `array`

```php
$data['status'] = 'success';
$data['msg'] = 'OK';
$aa = array();
if (!empty($countries)) {
    foreach ($countries as $row) {
        $b = $row['iso2'];
        $aa[$b] = array_push($row['name']);
    }
}
$data['result'] = $aa;

return setJSON($data);
```

this must be obtained:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "msg": "OK",
    "result": {
        /*"iso2": "name",*/
        "DE": "Germany"
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php but you probably want `$aa[$b] = $row['name'];`

Comment: @AbraCadaver, thanks! how to add iso2 ? ```"iso2":"name"``` now only "name" comes out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) takes an array and a value to add to it.  However the more common way would be just:

```
$aa[$row['iso2']] = $row['name'];
```

That being said, there is a built-in function so you don't have to loop and do it:

```
$data['status'] = 'success';
$data['msg'] = 'OK';

if (!empty($countries)) {
    $data['result'] = array_column($countries, 'name', 'iso2');
}
return setJSON($data);
```